# Sql query to get number of customers according to joining date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table "`Customers`".

It has a column name "`CreatedDate`", means it is a joining date of customer.

I want to calculate how many customer are between 1-5 years, 6-10 years, 11-15 years from current date to ceateddate, like below

```
Years         No of Customer
0-5           200
6-10          500
11-15         100
```

In detail if a customers createddate is "5-5-2010" than it should be in range of 0-5 years from current date.

And if createddate is "5-5-2006" than it should be in range of 6-10 years from current date.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I only tried   select count(CustomerID) as NoOfCustomer from Customers. I am newbei with database so don't know how to put condition for date.

Comment: Looks like I got beaten to it, haha.

Comment: Sorry @codemonkeh, what you mean?

Comment: By the time i saw your reply other people had already answered ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this:

```
with cte as (
  select ((datediff(yy, CreatedDate, getdate()) - 1) / 5) * 5 + 1 as d
  from Customers
)
select
  cast(d as nvarchar(max)) + '-' + cast(d + 4 as nvarchar(max)),
  count(*)
from cte
group by d
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7d69/7)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks @Roman, But it is not giving correct result. The oldest created date is "2008-01-18" in table and it is also giving result for 11-15. So I think some thing wrong here.

Comment: Sorry @Roman, My mistake, it has some dates older than 10 years. It is working fine, thanks again :-).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT '0-5' as [Years],COUNT(Customer) as [No of Customers] FROM dbo.Customers WHERE DATEDIFF(YY,CreatedDate,GETDATE()) <=5

UNION

SELECT '6-10' as [Years],COUNT(Customer) as [No of Customers] FROM dbo.Customers WHERE DATEDIFF(YY,CreatedDate,GETDATE()) >=5 AND DATEDIFF(YY,CreatedDate,GETDATE()) <=10

UNION

SELECT '11-15' as [Years],COUNT(Customer) as [No of Customers] FROM dbo.Customers WHERE DATEDIFF(YY,CreatedDate,GETDATE()) >=10 AND DATEDIFF(YY,CreatedDate,GETDATE()) <=15
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, But what about if there are more years like 16-20, 21-25 and so on ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
With s as(
    SELECT custid,CASE WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY,CREATEDATE,GETDATE())/365)>=1 
                                AND
                                FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY,CREATEDATE,GETDATE())/365)<=5 THEN '1-5'
                            WHEN 
                                FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY,CREATEDATE,GETDATE())/365)>=6 
                                AND
                                FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY,CREATEDATE,GETDATE())/365)<=10 THEN '6-10' END as 'd'
        FROM TABLE)
select count(custid),d
from s 
group by d
```